# Scope Chain in Javascript event handlers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, closures

I have a very interesting case where I am not able to figure out if I have got the concept of closure wrong or is the Chrome debugger going wrong in its output.

The code is here https://jsfiddle.net/ygjfutck/
I have put everything in HTML because that is how I was replicating it on my local machine. I am using Google Chrome v49.

In the event handler for #button click, I am incrementing variable `a` and putting the result in a HTML container. Interestingly, when I place a debug point using the Chrome Debug Tools, inside the event handler callback, and check the value of variable `b` in the console, the console throws an error that variable `b` is not defined.

**Note: When I say check the value of `b` in the console, it means that open up the chrome debug console and type `b` there. It does not mean using console.log() or any other similar method**

However if I change the event handler to this

```
    $("#button").click(function() {
        a = a + b;
        $selector.html(a);
    });
```

Then for the same debug point, b would now be defined in the console. 
I don't know what am I missing in terms of scope chain of event handlers or how the debugger views the same that is causing this behavior.

Note: 
If you are not able to place the debug point in jsfiddle, copy the HTML to a new file on your local machine and open it in Chrome.

The JS code for the above fiddle

```
<script>
  function outer() {
    var a;
    var b;
    var $selector;

    var retObj = {
      init: function() {
        a = 10;
        b = 5;
        $selector = $("#id");
        attachEventHandlers();
      }
    };

    function attachEventHandlers() {
      $("#button").click(function() {
        //place a debug point here and then in the console
        //b would not be defined
        //change the below statement to a = a+b, and in the console
        //b would be defined with the correct value
        a = a + 1;
        console.log(a);
        $selector.html(a);
      });
    }

    return retObj;
  }
  var obj = outer();
  obj.init();

</script>
```

Screenshot attached for the error (when running the same HTML on a separate page outside JSFiddle)
[image: The error as obtained in the chrome console on explicitly checking the value of b]

[image: Just mentioning <code>b</code> inside the event handler in any way, the console would show the correct value]

Comment: `b` appears defined at http://jsfiddle.net/ygjfutck/4

Comment: Ok I will edit my question. this is not what I meant by check in the console. I meant that explicitly open up the chrome debugger console and type b there.

Comment: Type `b` where at `console` ?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: added screenshots for both error and success cases

Comment: _"When I say check the value of `b` in the console, it means that open up the chrome debug console and type `b` there."_ You are receiving correct error. Why would `b` be defined ?

Comment: The same reason why `b` gets the value 5 automatically just by mentioning it there. Or for that matter `a` gets its values? Because as per my understanding it is accessible via the scope chain

Comment: i don't think the console is "scoped in" to your paused stack.